# Simple javascript wont load

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning to use html + javascript and I'm stuck at a homework right now with a quite simple code.
This is my html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <title>  Geolocation and Local Storage and CSS3 </title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" /> 
        </head>

    <body>
        <div> 
        Location:
        <button type="button" onclick="getLocation()"> Get Location </button>
        </div>

        <div id="holder">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the  external javascript :

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("holder");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var latlon = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;

    var img_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
    +latlon+"&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
    document.getElementById("holder").innerHTML = "<img src='"+img_url+"'>";
}
</script>
```

Weird thing is if I  get rid of the external file and just put the script inside the head it works, so I'm guessing its also not loading the external file which is weird, considering the path is correct.

Comment: Try taking away the `<script>` tags in the javascript file, and see if it works then.

Comment: I highly doubt the script would work if it was in the head. Your script is trying to read elements before they are rendered on the page. It is like someone calling your name before you walk into the room. Look at the developer console, I am sure it has an error message if the script is actually loading. The external javascript file should NOT have `<script></script>` in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second file isn't a Javascript file -- it's an HTML file with a Javascript section inside it.

Get rid of the `<script>` tags as Eli Sadoff said, and all will be well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove  tag on JavaScript file.
2. Check if your HTML and JavaScript file are in the same folder.
3. Check the name of your JavaScript file, is it the same you mentioned in the HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

The `<script>` tag is meant to embed your Javascript into your HTML file.

- Remove the script tags from your Javascript file
- Stick your link to your JS link right above the `</body>`

  Like this:

  `<body>
      <div> 
      Location:
      <button type="button" onclick="getLocation()"> Get Location </button>
      </div>
      <div id="holder">
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>
  </body>`